# Wrong IP with lighttpd reverse proxy

Tags: reverse-proxy, lighttpd, gunicorn

I use a lighttpd reverse proxy to serve django with gunicorn. Now this config worked:

```
proxy.server = ("" => ( "" => (
    "host" => "127.0.0.1",
    "port" => 8000,
)))
```

Now i moved the gunicorn into a container and use:

```
proxy.server = ("" => ( "" => (
    "host" => "192.168.1.2",
    "port" => 8000,
)))
```

Now every request has the ip `192.168.1.1` as seen by gunicorn. I would understand, if the reverse proxy obfuscates the real IP, but why did it work with localhost then?

for both i get

```
X-Forwarded-For: client-ip
X-Host: the.domain
X-Forwarded-Proto: http
```

where the client-ip is public ip space.

the requests comes from

host:

```
nc: connect to 127.0.0.1 8000 from localhost (127.0.0.1) 44953 [44953]
```

container:

```
nc: connect to 192.168.1.2 8000 from host (192.168.1.1) 60027 [60027]
```

the container itself has ip `192.168.1.2`, the host-bridge has `192.168.1.1` and the routes inside the container are:

```
default via 192.168.1.1 dev eth0 
192.168.1.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.2
```

the host has:

```
192.168.1.0/24 dev bridge  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.1
```

EDIT:
The X-Forwarded-For was the same for both requests. (Tested with `nc -vlp 8000`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My bet?  lighttpd is adding an `X-Forwarded-For` header, and Django has something hardcoded somewhere to know that `127.0.0.1` is unlikely to be the real remote IP address if that header's present.

You should verify that the `X-Forwarded-For` header is present, then get Django to use that as the remote address (looks like the way to do that is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4581789/how-do-i-get-user-ip-address-in-django)).

Comment: i added some more info. The X-Forwarded-For header seems correct, but its still not working. In both cases it should not be able to get ip info from the reverse proxy, so it must use the X-Forwarded-For header.

Comment: @allo Right - in a default config, the application won't just blindly trust an `X-Forwarded-For` header, as that would be a security problem (clients can send whatever, the header should only be trusted from trusted proxies).  Configuration in Django will be needed before it'll trust the `X-Forwarded-For` that lighttpd is sending.

Comment: okay, corrected the question again. you may be right, as server/client are 127.0.0.1 for the host scenario.

Comment: http://gunicorn-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/deploy.html says this, too. But ``--forwarded-allow-ips=real-ip`` and ``--forwarded-allow-ips='*'`` do not work for me.

Comment: Indeed, Django determines the real ip, and the ip determined by django is even logged in the gunicorn accesslog. I am using now a Middleware for the ip and it works: http://www.micahcarrick.com/django-ip-address-behind-nginx-proxy.html